# Get the arguments in line. With the following code, the lists get uneven, because the lists have different number of bullet points

Tags: formatting, two-column

I want to get the arguments in line.

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}



\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{\textbf{Positive}}
    
    
\begin{center}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Bla bla bla
    \item Bla bla bla
    \item Bla bla bla
    \item Bla bla bla
\end{itemize}
\end{center}

 
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}

  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{Negative}}
  
\begin{center}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Bla bla bla
    \item Bla bla bla
\end{itemize}
\end{center}
 
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  I'm also having trouble understanding what you mean by "arguments".

Comment: `\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}` (observe `[t]`)? Please, extend your code snipet to an MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete, self contained document, which we can copy and compile as it is.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko! It worked. I updated the code now, so it should be ready to be copied and compiled.

Comment: Any news? Does received answer help you? If it is, you may consider to accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is after editing your question solved. So only a off-topic suggestion how to make your code shorter and more clear:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{\textbf{Positive}}
    \begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla
\item Bla bla bla
\item Bla bla bla
\item Bla bla bla
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
    \textcolor{red}{\textbf{Negative}}
    \begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla
\item Bla bla bla
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following result:

[image]